# How to update target host of a request in Apache HttpClient?

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

Our signing algorithm update `HttpRequest`s by changing also the target
host of a request.

However, `org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec#execute` that prepares a given request for sending, computes target host before any `HttpRequestInterceptor` instance is run. Hence, even if `HttpRequestInterceptor` updates target host of a request, the request will be sent to the original host.

How can I update request target host so that the request is sent to an updated host?

I'm using httpclient 4.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try decorating the protocol executor and rewriting the origin request prior passing it down the execution pipeline

```
CloseableHttpClient client = new HttpClientBuilder() {

    @Override
    protected ClientExecChain decorateProtocolExec(final ClientExecChain protocolExec) {
        return new ClientExecChain() {
            @Override
            public CloseableHttpResponse execute(
                    final HttpRoute route,
                    final HttpRequestWrapper request,
                    final HttpClientContext clientContext,
                    final HttpExecutionAware execAware) throws IOException, HttpException {

                HttpUriRequest newRequest = RequestBuilder.copy(request.getOriginal())
                        .setUri("http://some-place-esle.com/")
                        .build();

                return protocolExec.execute(route, HttpRequestWrapper.wrap(newRequest), clientContext, execAware);
            }
        };
    }
}.build();
```